# how to read special nodes from xml and disaplay them on datagridview?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file whitch has the format like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Accounts>
  <account ID="000">
    <UserName>root</UserName>
    <Password>root</Password>
    <Permission>2</Permission>
  </account>
</Accounts>
```

I  just want to display the ID, UserName and Password as three columns on DataGridView.

Comment: What you got so far? Post some Code.

Comment: @Smartis I can just use the ReadXml method to get the whole file but don't know how to get special nodes and fill them to special columns of a datagridview.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'special nodes'. There are ways to bind the whole XML to the DataGrid - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mamta_m/binding-xml-to-a-wpf-datagrid/ - Or ways to do this over an DataSet - http://theprofessionalspoint.blogspot.co.at/2013/04/how-to-show-xml-in-wpf-datagrid-by.html

Comment: special nodes means: there has three childhodes in `account`,but i just want to get the two `username` and `password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may helps you:

```
 System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(YOUR XML FILE PATH);

 var result = doc.Element("Accounts").Elements("account").Select(i => new
 {
            Id = i.Attribute("ID").Value,
            User = i.Element("UserName").Value,
            Pass = i.Element("Password").Value
 }).ToList();
```

Then set the `result` as the `DataSource` of your `DataGrid`.

Comment: @wenLiangcan glad to be helpful